# Ember Select changing ids of contentBinding

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm attempting to use Ember Select but the id's of the options seem to be changing based on the selection I choose.

I've mocked up a simplified scenario with books and authors and have the below Ember.Select

```
{{ view Ember.Select
          contentBinding="controller.authors"
          optionValuePath="content.id"
          optionLabelPath="content.name"
          valueBinding="book.author.id"
}}
```

The select works, but it changes the underlying list that it is bound (contentBinding), not just the valueBinding.

Based on the bizarre behavior I'm seeing I can only assume that I'm wiring up the paramaters wrong on the Ember.Select call, but I can't come up with the right combination.

The fiddle below shows what I mean:

Steps to reproduce:
1) Click run in fiddle. Sometimes I have to hit it more than once to get the selects to populate (not sure why, it may have something to do with the issue, or may just be fiddle)
2) Change any "author" via the drop down
3) Notice that not only does the id associated with the book's author change, but the ids in the list of authors also change.
4) Tell me why :).

http://jsfiddle.net/davepreston/h9dJt/

As you can probably tell, I'm pretty new to ember, so thanks for any help.

--Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your binding to,

```
view Ember.Select
          contentBinding="controller.authors"
          optionValuePath="content"
          optionLabelPath="content.name"
          valueBinding="book.author"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h9dJt/4/

Comment: That makes sense, but if I set valueBinding to "book.author" the select isn't defaulted to the correct value anymore. (more specifically, all the drop downs start with "Bob" although book 2 should be "Sue")

Comment: Indeed, this happens because the author instances in the lists are not common with the author instances contained within the book instances. Ember.Select checks if any value from the list is equal and since nothing is it does not render the relationship.  Look at the following fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h9dJt/6/ where Ember.Select has been omitted and if you use ember's chrome console debugging tools check out the references between the theBooks and theAuthors. A work around would be to either not use ember.select and create your own impl or not use em-data and take care of common refs.

Comment: One thing to note. I finally got Ember.Select to work properly once I stopped using async attributes. If the attributes are async: 'true' then the default value was not properly set. Once I changed them to inline attributes and used the above code things worked. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 1):

The answer to 4) why? 
This is because of the you have binding between value of selection with book.author.id so when the selection value changes, id of corresponding author also changes. This is the usual behavior of basic 2 way bindings of ember. In which if we bind 2 attributes, change of one changes the other one too.
id change is reflected in the list of authors because in the store we only have one instance of the record means book.author refer to the same record object (does not make a copy).

Comment: Okay, so what I'm attempting to do is bind to the current value of author for the book in question, so that I can change which author is associated with the book. It makes sense that binding to the id of the author wouldn't work (for the reasons you mentioned), now I'm hoping someone can help me bind to the association itself so that I can change the book's author without changing the author.